# Display NSIDC arctic ice extent using PolarMap.js?

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, arctic

I'm a newbie in GIS. I've built a map of an expedition across the arctic region, but right now the trek is displayed across the ocean. To fix this, I've tried to integrate ice extent shapefiles from NSIDC, and I've successfully included one onto my polarMap.js map using a Leaflet plugin.  It is not displayed in the right place, though.

I believe the coordindate system is a mismatch, and reprojection is necessary. I'm struggling to figure out how to make this data transformation.

Here is a link to my CI server, in case you want to see the .js code I have so far: http://petrichor.mynetgear.com:8008/map.html

I can probably figure out the details of implementation, but I just haven't been able to figure out the big picture. How does one approach this reprojection requirement?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a graphical comment/clarification than answer, but hopefully you can see that the [NSDIC shapefiles](ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/NOAA/G02135/north/monthly/shapefiles/shp_extent/10_Oct/) are in [EPSG:3413](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3413), and correctly align with another EPSG:3413 backdrop (from a WMS), so the NSDIC shapefiles aren't faulty.

Your track data is in degrees lat/long, but EPSG:3413 length units are metres, so you will need to either reproject your data or the shapefiles.

[image: NSDIC ice sheet shapefile on NSDIC backdrop]